# FTP for my clients

Tags: ftp, cloud-hosting

Do you know of a FTP service that have a good looking web interface so that clients can login in, download files and upload files. Preferably customizable so i can put my brand on it. And that uses a cloud service like Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not FTP per se, [YouSendIt](http://yousendit.com) has been around for a while, is reasonably priced and is fairly trivial to embed the upload form into your Website to allow files to be securely transferred to you.

Once a file has been uploaded, you receive an email notification with a password-protected download link.

Another option would be to roll your own with an Amazon EC2 instance running [PHFTP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phftp/) backed by S3 storage.